# Simple, Lightweighted, Easier to Learn PHP Ecommerce Package

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart, checkout

I wish to have an Ecommerce solution where admin can add category, add products within category, shopping cart, checkout(using paypal).

I knew Magento supports this pretty well, but we have short time frame now for development(1-2 weeks), and therefore we need something simpler and lightweighted that we can learn it fast, and customized it fast.

I would like to hear you recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) may work well for you, or, just develop it in-house.

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2.0](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) is really awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [OSCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/). It has a wide and growing community support.

As per their website, they have [12,819](http://shops.oscommerce.com/)  live stores, 6997 Add-ons so far.

You can download the source code [here](http://www.oscommerce.com/solutions/downloads).